# Platform Event with Process Builder to Update Contacts Related to an Account

Tags: process-builder, platform-event

In a scenario where an account has a number of contacts. When a field on the account changes, need to propagate that value to all related contacts. I know it can be done with a visual flow and Apex trigger but not Process Builder. Could I use platform event to watch for that value change on the account and publish account Id and new value so related contacts can see it and update themselves by using a Process Builder?

In other words, can I utilize platform events to update children from a parent?

Answer (score 1):

You definitely can update child records when the parent changed via Process Builder.

When you create an action in PB make sure to select the "Select a record related to the Account" option in the Record Type section.

[image]

Then select Contacts and define new field values for the records you update.

[image]

Now you are all set.